# How to mod_rewrite from path to query?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have url like:

`http://olddomain.com/demo?abc=ced&ghi=jkl`

And I would like to rewrite it to separate domain as query:

`http://newdomain.com/legacy?url=http%3A%2F%2Folddomain.com%2Fdemo%3Fabc%3Ddef%26ghi%3Djkl`

Right now I have something like this:

`RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/legacy?url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}`

The problem is that the output is:

`http://newdomain.com/?url=olddomain.com/demo?abc=def&ghi=jkl`

So no `http://` and characters /, ?, = and & are not escaped. In addition to that if there will be no query in original requests there will be trailing ?, but that's probably not big problem.

Comment: Where is this part of the appended query: `&ghi=jkl` in the incoming URL? `http://olddomain.com/` should be replaced with `http://example.com/` in the substitution URL?

Comment: Yes - there were several typos here. `&ghi=jkl` should be included in original path and `http://example.com/` should be `http://olddomain.com/` - it is now fixed in question.